# How to merge two JavaScript Object litterals

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

If I have the objects data1 and data2, how can I make data3?

I will send data3 as a parameter later in my AJAX request calling a MVC Server controller. (Just saying I can't have data3 to be an array I think).

```
var data1 = {
    managementPointId: 1,
    businessUnitId: 2
};

var data2 = {
    computerPackageId: 3
};

var data3 = {
    managementPointId: 1,
    businessUnitId: 2,
    computerPackageId: 3
};
```

Comment: data3 = [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)({}, data1, data2);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method:

```js
var data1 = {
    managementPointId: 1,
    businessUnitId: 2
};

var data2 = {
    computerPackageId: 3
};

var data3 = $.extend({}, data1, data2);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data3, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice it works. So simple. My didn't I ask this many months ago :) Thanks. (I will accept when I can in 10mins)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested to do in plain javascript,

simply declare a var like

var obj3 = yourfunction(obj1,obj2,obj3);

and in your function write a nested for loop which loops for arguments and loops through all props in objs provided and returns the obj.

try it . 
take care about null checks and other corner cases like object checking etc...,

Answer (score 1):

Using plain JavaScript:

```js
function extend(a, b){
    for(var key in b)
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(key))
            a[key] = b[key];
    return a;
}


var data1 = {
    managementPointId: 1,
    businessUnitId: 2
};

var data2 = {
    computerPackageId: 3
};
var data3 = extend(data1, data2);


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data3, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```